# unable to import module error in pylint

Tags: sonarqube, pylint, sonar-runner

I am playing around with pylint and using sonarqube for code analysis. Everything is installed and working fine. However I am getting error "f0401" saying that I am unable to import module. Here is my directory structure.

```
top level:
    directoryA
        __init__.py
        folderA
        some .py files        
    directoryB
        __init__.py
        folderA
        some .py files
    directoryC
        __init__.py
        folderA
        some .py files
```

I am running pylint on directoryA. the .py files in directoryA have some imports from the directoryB and directoryC. So when I run pylint on directoryA i get import errors such as unable to 'import directoryB.somemodule'. I hope that I am able to explain it clearly.

Can some body help he how to solve that problem. P.S. It will be great if some ´body point me out to some good documentation and tutorials for using and tweaking pylint.

Answer (score 3):

Pylint rely on proper `PYTHONPATH` being set. What happens if you type `python toplevel/directoryA/file.py`? Imports should work then.

Hint: if they don't, you probably want to run `export PYTHONPATH=toplevel`, or something like that.

Comment: I am not sure how to set PYTHONPATH. I am newbie and trying to learn. I have tried exporting PYTHONPATH the way you said but it didnt worked. Is tere any thing related to VIRTALENV? I am using VIRTENV.

Answer (score 2):

pylint will take current directory as a part of PYTHONPATH (which is just a environment variable indicates where python interpreter should search for packages).

Thus if you run pylint in **dirA**, it knows all things in dir A (e.g. folder A) and others in standard PYTHONPATH, but not dir B since pylint does not know where to find *directoryB.somemodule*.

The simplest solution is run pylint xxxx in **root of your project**. Otherwise you have to add it to PYTHONPATH, or use a pylintrc file (suggested).

For more detail for pylint run, check [its document](http://docs.pylint.org/faq.html#running-pylint) for detail